Flutter Build APK Error: Android Resource Linking Failed
I'm trying to build an APK for my Flutter project, but I keep running into an error. Here are my current configurations:

Gradle Version: 8.9

JDK Version: 21

AGP Version: 8.7.2

Android SDK Version: 33



/// gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-bin.zip


/// settings.gradle
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.5.0" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.0" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.9.9" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}


/// build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        agp_version = '8.7.2'
    }
}


/// app/build.gradle
android {
    namespace "com.learnProject.project"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion "27.0.12077973"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.learnProject.project"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

Issue
When I run the Android build command (./gradlew assembleRelease), it completes successfully. However, when I try flutter build apk, I get the following error:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_bluetooth_serial:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed

I expected the APK build to complete successfully since the Android build (./gradlew assembleRelease) worked without any issues. To troubleshoot, I tried the following steps:

Checked Gradle and Plugin Versions: Verified that my Gradle, Android Gradle Plugin, and Kotlin versions were compatible with my project setup.

Cleaned and Rebuilt the Project: Ran flutter clean and rebuilt the project, but it didn’t resolve the issue.

Updated Dependencies: Updated some of my dependencies to make sure they were compatible with Gradle 8.9 and JDK 21.

Tried Different Compile SDK Versions: Adjusted the compileSdk and targetSdk versions to see if that would make a difference, but the error persisted.


Despite these attempts, the error still appears during flutter build apk, specifically on the :flutter_bluetooth_serial:verifyReleaseResources task. Any insights into why this is happening or suggestions for additional steps to try would be very helpful.
